# When multiple channel forms present each containing a matrix, the add row button adds multiple rows

Tags: matrix, channel-form

When a page contains multiple channel forms on the same page, each with a matrix field; the Add Row button adds multiple rows (1 per channel form on the page it seems.)

Is there any easy way to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

After examining some pseudo-related questions I discovered that multiple instances of the matrix.js were being loaded causing multiple executions upon the Add Row click event.  I added `include_assets="no"` on channel forms after the first one which prevented the problem.